# Null value in DB displays content on page

Tags: database

I have a blank category box on the bottom of the following page (http://www.suncorstainless.com/stainless-steel-hardware) and it appears that it's caused by a Null value in a table somewhere in my DB. I'm not the developer of this website and am having a hard time determining where this issue is in the DB.

Are there any tools available to determine the DB table that is displaying content on a page?

Thanks-in-Advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel) and enable it's database query log. See [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1298/how-can-i-output-the-devel-query-log).

Comment: Thanks Thomas4019, Now I just have to figure out all of the output on that page. There are a ton of SELECt statements

Comment: Yes, Drupal does use many queries one a single page. Given your page I would look for queries that include something like "body", "title" or "image". You can also try executing the SELECT statements and see what they look like.